# Generate random questions in swift

Tags: swift

Can anyone help? I have a true or false game, however, I want the questions to be shuffled/random. I know there is previous shuffle answers but I can't get my head around it. For example, the questions in the append section should appear at random. I have been trying different things for days. I had a look at arc4random but I had a hard time implementing it. I don't want to be spoon fed but a decent answer is all I am looking for.

Here is my swift code

```
//  ViewController.swift
 //  TrueOrFalse
 //
  // 
   //

     import UIKit


      class ViewController: UIViewController {
        // Classes
         class newLabel:UILabel {
              convenience required init(width:CGFloat,                                     height:CGFloat,              framewidth: CGFloat, frameheight: CGFloat) {
        self.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, framewidth, frameheight))
        self.center = CGPointMake(width, height)
        self.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 18)
    }

}

class newButton:UIButton {
    var button:UIButton!
    convenience required init(width:CGFloat, height:CGFloat, framewidth: CGFloat, frameheight: CGFloat) {
        self.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, framewidth, frameheight))
        self.button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        self.center = CGPointMake(width, height)
    }
}

let width:CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
let height:CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height

var model:ToFModel = ToFModel()
var statement:UILabel!
var correctCount:newLabel!
var incorrectCount:newLabel!
var timerCount:newLabel!
var correctAmt:Int = 0
var incorrectAmt:Int = 0
var buttonTrue:newButton!
var buttonFalse:newButton!
var count:Int = 0
var counter:Int = 60
var answer:String!
var wall:UIView!
var lastBool:String!
var displayLastBool:newLabel!
var questionNumber:newLabel!
var frame:UIImageView!
var image:UIImage!
var splashImage:UIImage!
var splashLandingText:UILabel!
var splashButtonStart:newButton!
var timer = NSTimer()
var userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


func nextIter() {
    statement.text = model.statements[count][0]
    answer = model.statements[count][1]
    questionNumber.text = "Question- \(count+1)/\(model.statements.count)"

    if count == model.statements.count-1{
       statement.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    else{
        statement.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    if count > 0 && count < model.statements.count {

        // displayLastBool.text = ""
        view.addSubview(displayLastBool)
    }
    else {
        displayLastBool.text = ""
    }
    count += 1
}

// View functions
func start(sender:newButton) {
    count = 0
    frame.image = image
    displayLastBool = newLabel(width: 170, height: height*0.27, framewidth: 200, frameheight: 50)

    //Timer
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: Selector("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    // Put the image into the frame
    // Remove current stuff
    splashButtonStart.removeFromSuperview()
    splashLandingText.removeFromSuperview()
    // Add stuff to view
    view.addSubview(timerCount)
    view.addSubview(correctCount)
    view.addSubview(incorrectCount)
    view.addSubview(statement)
    view.addSubview(buttonTrue)
    view.addSubview(buttonFalse)
    view.addSubview(questionNumber)
    nextIter()
}


func splashPage() {
    count = 0
    displayLastBool?.removeFromSuperview()

    // Put up the wall
    view.addSubview(wall)
    // Hang the frame on the wall
    wall.addSubview(frame)
    // Put up the text
    view.addSubview(splashLandingText)
    // Put up the button
    view.addSubview(splashButtonStart)
    frame.image = splashImage

}

func reset() {
    correctCount.hidden = true
    incorrectCount.hidden = true
    count = 0
    incorrectAmt = 0
    correctAmt = 0
    correctCount.removeFromSuperview()
    incorrectCount.removeFromSuperview()
    statement.removeFromSuperview()
    buttonFalse.removeFromSuperview()
    buttonTrue.removeFromSuperview()
    questionNumber.removeFromSuperview()
    displayLastBool.removeFromSuperview()
    splashPage()
}

// Boolean detection
func boolResponse(sender:newButton) {
    if count == model.statements.count {
        if answer == String(sender.tag) {
            count = 0
            correctAmt = 0
            incorrectAmt = 0
            correctCount.hidden = true
            incorrectCount.hidden = true

            displayLastBool.hidden = false

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: Selector("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        }
        else {
            timer.invalidate()
            reset()
        }
    }
    else if answer == String(sender.tag) {
        lastBool = "Correct"
        displayLastBool.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        // Correct count increments here
        correctAmt += 1
    }
    else if answer != String(sender.tag) {
        lastBool = "Incorrect"
        displayLastBool.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        // Incorrect count increments here
        incorrectAmt += 1
        count = 9;
    }
    if count == model.statements.count-1 {
        correctCount.hidden = false
        incorrectCount.hidden = false

        correctCount.text = "Correct- \(correctAmt)"
        //incorrectCount.text = "Incorrect- \(incorrectAmt)"


        //Saving Highscore
        var highscore=userDefaults.integerForKey("highscore")

        if(correctAmt>highscore)
        {
            userDefaults.setInteger(correctAmt, forKey: "highscore")
        }
        var highscoreshow=userDefaults.integerForKey("highscore")
        incorrectCount.text = "High Score- \(highscoreshow)"





        timer.invalidate()
        counter = 60
        timerCount.text = String(counter)
        timerCount.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    nextIter()
}

//Timer update function
func updateCounter() {
    timerCount.text = String(counter--)

    if counter <= 9{
        timerCount.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }else{
        timerCount.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    if counter == 0{
        count=9
        nextIter()
        resetTimer()
    }
}

//Timer reset function
func resetTimer() {
    correctCount.hidden = false
    incorrectCount.hidden = false

    correctCount.text = "Correct- \(correctAmt)"
    incorrectCount.text = "Incorrect- \(incorrectAmt)"
    timer.invalidate()
    counter = 60
    timerCount.text = String(counter)
    timerCount.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

   // displayLastBool.hidden = true
    //questionNumber.hidden = true
}


// Make an image view that you can modify from any function in this class
var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    // Append




    model.statementsAppend("Sneezes regularly exceed 200 mph.", bool: "0")
    model.statementsAppend("Virtually all Las Vegas gambling casinos ensure that they have no clocks.", bool: "1")
    model.statementsAppend("Two human lungs have a surface area of approximately 750 square feet.", bool: "1")
    model.statementsAppend("The 'black box' in an airplane is colored black.", bool: "0")
    model.statementsAppend("The Statue of Liberty was a gift from Germany to America.", bool: "0")
    model.statementsAppend("Ozone is helpful in the trophosphere but damaging to the stratosphere.", bool: "0")
    model.statementsAppend("The can opener was invented after the can.", bool: "1")
    model.statementsAppend("The world's oldest tree is OVER 9000 years old.", bool:"1")
    model.statementsAppend("Emus can fly.", bool: "0")
    model.statementsAppend("Game Over \n Play again?", bool: "1")




    // Make the wall, the frame, and the image for the frame
    wall = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))
    frame = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height))

    //Load the text
    statement = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, height))
    statement.center = CGPointMake(width/2, height*0.5)
    statement.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    statement.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    statement.numberOfLines = 99
    statement.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 24)

    splashImage = UIImage(named: "splashGradient")
    image = UIImage(named: "minimalGradient")

    //Load the counts
    timerCount = newLabel(width: 100, height: height*0.10, framewidth:200, frameheight:100)
    correctCount = newLabel(width: 159, height: height*0.15, framewidth:100, frameheight:50)
    incorrectCount = newLabel(width:147, height: height*0.19, framewidth:130, frameheight:50)
    questionNumber = newLabel(width: 197, height: height*0.23, framewidth: 200, frameheight: 50)

    timerCount.center = CGPointMake(width/2, height*0.09)
    timerCount.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    timerCount.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 40)
    timerCount.text = String(counter)

    correctCount.text = "Correct- \(correctAmt)"
    incorrectCount.text = "High Score- \(incorrectAmt)"
    incorrectCount.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    lastBool = "Incorrect"

    correctCount.hidden = true
    incorrectCount.hidden = true
    questionNumber.hidden = true

    //Load the buttons
    buttonTrue = newButton(width: 80, height: height/1.2, framewidth: 111, frameheight: 45)
    buttonFalse = newButton(width: 240, height: height/1.2, framewidth: 111, frameheight: 45)
    // Style of button
    buttonTrue.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "true"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    buttonFalse.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "false"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    // .tag
    buttonTrue.tag = 1
    buttonFalse.tag = 0

    // Functions if button is clicked
    buttonTrue.addTarget(self, action: "boolResponse:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    buttonFalse.addTarget(self, action: "boolResponse:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    // Make the splash button
    splashButtonStart = newButton(width: width/2, height: height*0.8, framewidth: 244, frameheight: 58)
    splashButtonStart.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "splashButton"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    splashButtonStart.addTarget(self, action: "start:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    // Configure the text on the splash page
    splashLandingText = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 280))
    splashLandingText.center = CGPointMake(width/2, height*0.4)
    splashLandingText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    splashLandingText.numberOfLines = 99
    splashLandingText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    splashLandingText.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 24)
    splashLandingText.text = "Impossible True or False \n \n Are you ready to start your journey?"


    // Configure the statement
    splashPage()
```

}

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try to wade through your code. It's too much. (tldr)
Here is a general solution. You'll need to adapt it to your needs.
Create a struct that contains a question, the possible answers, and the correct answer (if they are all true/false questions you could skip the possible answers part.) Let's call it questionStruct.

Then create an array of questionStruct structures. Populate it with questions.

Copy the list of all questions into a working array of questions. Let's call it remainingQuestions

Then user arc4random_uniform to select a question at random and remove it from the remaining questions array

```
let index = arc4random_uniform(remainingQuestions.count)
let aQuestion = remainingQuestions.removeAtIndex(index)
```

When the remainingQuestions array is empty, repopulate it with the array of all questions to start over.